# How to add image role programmatically in magento2

Tags: magento2, adminhtml

I want to add image role in my custom page in admin side. There are four image role in core part . I want to add same as in my custom page.

How to add it in my custom page as mentioned in image

please help me.... 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add new image type using this code (from setup data script of your module):

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * EAV setup factory
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'attribute_image_code',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Image Attribute Name (Label)',
                'input' => 'media_image',
                'frontend' => 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Frontend\Image',
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'filterable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'sort_order' => 10,
                'required' => false,
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

Replace `attribute_image_code` with code of your own attribute and do not forget to rename attribute label.

Comment: I want to add in phtml file...how to add it?

Comment: I don't want to add new image type... i want to use image role which is already available in core

Comment: Please, add code to clarify you question

Comment: @RohanHapani did you find a solution? This answer seems to just add a new EAV property and not update the Role list

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau I want to assign this role to multiple images any idea??